# How to remove recaptcha in Flutter phone auth

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am developing a Flutter app for both Android and iOS devices. Iam using Phone authentication from firebase. The firebase phone auth redirects the user to webpage for recaptcha verification everytime the user tries to login.

The solutions I have already tried :

1. Adding SHA-1 and SHA-256 to my firebase project.
2. Enabling Android Device verification API for my project in Google play console.

Please help me to remove the recaptcha.

I have figured out that this is happening only for rooted devices. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: i have faced the same issue but could not get any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

According to firebase :

If device is rooted or have unlocked bootloader they do not pass SafetyNet checks. As such, it defaults to the reCAPTCHA verification. You can follow the steps mentioned [here](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/locking_unlocking) to lock the bootloader or test your app on unrooted device.